# How to show an image in the background of a surface plot in vispy?

Tags: python, image, plot, background, vispy

I want to have a surface plot in vispy, but also display a 2D image in place of the white background.

I used vispy's [Draw a SurfacePlot](https://vispy.org/gallery/scene/surface_plot.html) example as a base. The first thing I tried is just adding a `scene.visuals.Image` object to the view, but that ended up rendering the image as one of the objects in the 3D scene:

```py
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', bgcolor='w')
background_texture = scene.visuals.Image(np.random.rand(512, 512, 3).astype(np.float32))

view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(up='z', fov=60)
view.add(background_texture)

...
```

[I don't have reputation to display images: failed image background surfaceplot attempt #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH5p4.png)

Since the image needs to be rendered in the background, I figured it needs its own 2D view on top of which the 3D scene of the `SurfacePlot` will be rendered, so I created a new view for the image:

```py
canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', bgcolor='w')
background_texture = scene.visuals.Image(np.random.rand(512, 512, 3).astype(np.float32))

viewbg = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
viewbg.add(background_texture)

view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(up='z', fov=60)

...
```

However, the image is rendered on top of the surface plot, with the exception of axis labels which are rendered on top of the image. Reordering `view` and `viewbg` code so `view` is created first doesn't make a difference; it only makes things worse because then I also lose the ability to interact with the surface plot.

[I don't have reputation to display images: failed image background surfaceplot attempt #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e79K.jpg)

Is there a way to render the entire 3D scene on top of the image?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the background image to be a *static* background of the entire canvas, right? That is, it doesn't respond to mouse events, right? In that case, when you create your `Image` pass `parent=canvas.scene`. At least I think this is how it is done. Basically you are saying "image, you aren't a child of the camera view, you are a child of the overall canvas".

Comment: @djhoese That's exactly right, I want a static background image to my canvas. I tried only creating an `Image` and passing `parent=canvas.scene` right after creating the `SceneCanvas` and the image is still rendered on top of the surface plot, excluding axis labels, just like in the second image I linked in the question.

Comment: You'll likely need to play with the coordinates of your Image and possibly add an `image.transform = STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -100))` or similar (maybe positive Z?) to force the image to be behind everything else in the display. You can also provide a `scale=(x, y, z)` to that transform to force it to a reasonable size for your window. Since you aren't attached to the camera you may need to do some manual manipulation of the transform if the user resizes the window. I don't know for sure as I don't normally do this myself.

Comment: @djhoese I tried playing with translations and the image disappears if its Z coordinate falls outside the range of [-1, 1). Otherwise, the effect remains the same as before.

I can think of the following types of solutions, but I don't have the knowledge to execute any of them within VisPy:
1. Do the equivalent of drawing a textured quad in OpenGL with an orthographic projection, then setting the perspective projection and drawing the 3D scene.
2. Influence the rendering order within VisPy's widgets in a way that the image is drawn first, then the 3D scene is drawn on top.

Guidance pls?

Comment: If this becomes complicated to solve, maybe a GitHub issue would be a better place to discuss this? I hacked my last comment to be right within the character limit here...

Comment: @djhoese Update: the following works: `image.transform = STTransform(translate=(0, 0, 0.9999))`. This way both the surface plot and the axis labels are plotted on top of the static image. However, if I add more 9's to this number, then suddenly axis labels are no longer plotted on top the image. This current solution works, although if you zoom in on the surface plot enough eventually the image will be rendered in front of a part of the plot and axes. I think the most ideal solution would be to somehow clear the depth buffer after drawing the static image, and then draw the 3D scene.

Comment: I assume with the extra 9's the image is on top again? So going to 0 (or even -1) is the wrong direction? You could also translate the plot Visual so it isn't right on the edge of the buffer space. There is also an aspect of drawing order, but I'm not sure how this works when these 2 Visuals are from separate parents. You could trying `image.order = -100` or something like to try to force it being drawn first.

Comment: Nah, with the extra 9's the image is not on top again, but the axis labels disappear under the image. I've since moved things around in the scene graph and this artifact seemingly no longer appears, so the extra 9's seem to work fine now. I've made the `Image` a child of `canvas.central_widget`, just like the `ViewBox` is. From what I've seen, the `order` property is only relevant for nodes that have the same direct parent. There's a helpful function that displays the rendering order. I'll play around some more and post an answer here once I've refined my solution.

Comment: Sounds good. If you need more help with this you could also create an issue on the vispy github which makes longer conversations like this easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to guidance from [@djhoese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433202/djhoese), I was able to come up with some solutions. First and foremost, the background image must be outside of `view` in the scene graph, lest it becomes a part of the 3D space displayed by the view's `TurntableCamera`. After that comes the problem of actually displaying the image behind the 3D scene.

## Solution 1: Clear the OpenGL depth buffer after drawing the image and before drawing the 3D scene

The cleanest approach would be to first draw the image, then clear the OpenGL depth buffer before drawing the 3D scene. This will ensure that the scene is drawn on top of the image. The easiest way to do this would be to subclass `scene.Image` and add a call to `gloo.clear(color=False, depth=True)` after drawing:

```py
class BackgroundImage(scene.Image):
    def draw(self):
        super().draw()
        gloo.clear(color=False, depth=True)
```

Ensure that `BackgroundImage` is rendered before anything else. Full code below:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

from vispy import app, scene, gloo
from vispy.util.filter import gaussian_filter


class BackgroundImage(scene.Image):
    def draw(self):
        super().draw()
        gloo.clear(color=False, depth=True)


canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', bgcolor='w')

view_bg = canvas.central_widget.add_view(camera=scene.PanZoomCamera())
view_bg.order = float("-inf")  # For good measure

background_image = BackgroundImage(np.random.rand(512, 512, 3).astype(np.float32), parent=view_bg.scene)
view_bg.camera.set_range(margin=0)

view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(up='z', fov=60)

# Simple surface plot example
# x, y values are not specified, so assumed to be 0:50
z = np.random.normal(size=(250, 250), scale=200)
z[100, 100] += 50000
z = gaussian_filter(z, (10, 10))
p1 = scene.visuals.SurfacePlot(z=z, color=(0.3, 0.3, 1, 1))
p1.transform = scene.transforms.MatrixTransform()
p1.transform.scale([1/249., 1/249., 1/249.])
p1.transform.translate([-0.5, -0.5, 0])

view.add(p1)

# p1._update_data()  # cheating.
# cf = scene.filters.ZColormapFilter('fire', zrange=(z.max(), z.min()))
# p1.attach(cf)


xax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5]], tick_direction=(0, -1),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
xax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

yax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 0.5]], tick_direction=(-1, 0),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
yax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

# Add a 3D axis to keep us oriented
axis = scene.visuals.XYZAxis(parent=view.scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvas.show()
    if sys.flags.interactive == 0:
        app.run()
```

A `PanZoomCamera` is used with `background_image` to ensure that the image is scaled to fit the entire canvas. You won't be able to interact with that camera since the view with the `TurntableCamera` is drawn on top so it takes focus.

[I don't have reputation to embed images in my answer: surface plot with a background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNSTK.jpg)

### Generalizing the solution to draw any scene in the background

If you want to draw any scene, not just an `Image` in the background of another scene, you can implement a `Node` subclass that clears the depth buffer after its children are drawn. It's probably best to inherit from `Widget` since it provides the most features:

```py
class Background(scene.Widget):
    """Node that clears the depth buffer after drawing its children."""
    ClearDepth = type("ClearDepthBuffer", (scene.Node,), {'draw': lambda self: gloo.clear(color=False, depth=True)})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._last = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._last = self.ClearDepth(parent=self)
        self._last.order = float("inf")
        assert self._children.pop() == self._last

    @property
    def children(self):
        return super().children + [self._last] if self._last is not None else super().children
```

Make sure that `Background` is actually drawn before anything else. Full surface plot code with this approach below:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

from vispy import app, scene, gloo
from vispy.util.filter import gaussian_filter


class Background(scene.Widget):
    """Node that clears the depth buffer after drawing its children."""
    ClearDepth = type("ClearDepthBuffer", (scene.Node,), {'draw': lambda self: gloo.clear(color=False, depth=True)})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._last = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._last = self.ClearDepth(parent=self)
        self._last.order = float("inf")
        assert self._children.pop() == self._last

    @property
    def children(self):
        return super().children + [self._last] if self._last is not None else super().children


canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', bgcolor='w')

background = canvas.central_widget.add_widget(Background())
background.order = float("-inf")  # For good measure
view_bg = background.add_view(camera=scene.PanZoomCamera())

background_image = scene.Image(np.random.rand(512, 512, 3).astype(np.float32), parent=view_bg.scene)
view_bg.camera.set_range(margin=0)

view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(up='z', fov=60)

print(canvas.scene.describe_tree())

# Simple surface plot example
# x, y values are not specified, so assumed to be 0:50
z = np.random.normal(size=(250, 250), scale=200)
z[100, 100] += 50000
z = gaussian_filter(z, (10, 10))
p1 = scene.visuals.SurfacePlot(z=z, color=(0.3, 0.3, 1, 1))
p1.transform = scene.transforms.MatrixTransform()
p1.transform.scale([1/249., 1/249., 1/249.])
p1.transform.translate([-0.5, -0.5, 0])

view.add(p1)

# p1._update_data()  # cheating.
# cf = scene.filters.ZColormapFilter('fire', zrange=(z.max(), z.min()))
# p1.attach(cf)


xax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5]], tick_direction=(0, -1),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
xax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

yax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 0.5]], tick_direction=(-1, 0),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
yax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

# Add a 3D axis to keep us oriented
axis = scene.visuals.XYZAxis(parent=view.scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvas.show()
    if sys.flags.interactive == 0:
        app.run()
```

Make sure to use the `add_widget` and `add_view` methods when using `Widget` or a subclass of `Widget` so canvas events are handled for you properly. The neat thing about this approach is that you can have multiple `Background` instances rendered in a row, with each one being rendered on top of the previous, providing you with a multi-layered background where each background can be an arbitrary 2D or 3D scene.

## Solution 2: Use translate and scale transforms on the image outside of a view

An alternative to clearing the OpenGL depth buffer would be to translate the `Image` so its `z` coordinate is as close to `1.0` as possible, but not actually equal to `1.0`. This approach won't work with `PanZoomCamera`, though, so you will also have to handle the scaling of the image so its fits the entire canvas once the canvas is resized. The `resize` event is also called during initial canvas setup. Full code below:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

from vispy import app, scene
from vispy.util.filter import gaussian_filter
from vispy.visuals.transforms import STTransform

canvas = scene.SceneCanvas(keys='interactive', bgcolor='w')

background_image = scene.Image(np.random.rand(512, 512, 3).astype(np.float32), parent=canvas.central_widget)
canvas.events.resize.connect(lambda _: background_image.__setattr__('transform', STTransform(
    translate=(0, 0, 0.999999970197677556793536268742172978818416595458984374),
    scale=tuple(c / b for c, b in zip(canvas.size, background_image.size))
)))

view = canvas.central_widget.add_view()
view.camera = scene.TurntableCamera(up='z', fov=60)

# Simple surface plot example
# x, y values are not specified, so assumed to be 0:50
z = np.random.normal(size=(250, 250), scale=200)
z[100, 100] += 50000
z = gaussian_filter(z, (10, 10))
p1 = scene.visuals.SurfacePlot(z=z, color=(0.3, 0.3, 1, 1))
p1.transform = scene.transforms.MatrixTransform()
p1.transform.scale([1/249., 1/249., 1/249.])
p1.transform.translate([-0.5, -0.5, 0])

view.add(p1)

# p1._update_data()  # cheating.
# cf = scene.filters.ZColormapFilter('fire', zrange=(z.max(), z.min()))
# p1.attach(cf)


xax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [0.5, -0.5]], tick_direction=(0, -1),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
xax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

yax = scene.Axis(pos=[[-0.5, -0.5], [-0.5, 0.5]], tick_direction=(-1, 0),
                 font_size=16, axis_color='k', tick_color='k', text_color='k',
                 parent=view.scene)
yax.transform = scene.STTransform(translate=(0, 0, -0.2))

# Add a 3D axis to keep us oriented
axis = scene.visuals.XYZAxis(parent=view.scene)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    canvas.show()
    if sys.flags.interactive == 0:
        app.run()
```

With this approach you don't have to worry about drawing the `Image` before the 3D scene. Any drawing order works. If the image doesn't show, its `z` coordinate is probably being rounded up to `1.0`, so try to remove a few decimals in the `translate` parameter of `STTransform`. Values of `0.9999` and upwards should work well enough. I just went and found the maximum possible value I could put in the `z` coordinate that would display the image for me.